# jquery doesn't run after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with **JQuery** in **dynamic page** .
I have a select input:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

and a text input:

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="123456789"></input>
```

and i wrote in my scripts:

```
function changeLength(){
    var place = document.getElementById('input');
    var placeText = 0;
    placeText = place.value;
    if(placeText.length > 5){
        place.style.fontSize = "10px";
    }
}

$(body).on("change","#select",function(){//AJAX is called
    changeLength();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    changeLength();
});
```

function `changeLength` is working *before* Ajax calling but *after* isn't.

Comment: why are you mixing vanilla with jquery?is there a special reason?

Comment: Where is your ajax function?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say it's working or not working? And could you share the code you've omitted (where you wrote "AJAX is called")?

Comment: Where is `body` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is usually because the html select input is deleted and reconstructed in the page after the ajax request and you will need to register the handler again by doing another call to the following after the ajax is completed:

```
$(body).on("change","#select",function(){//AJAX is called
    changeLength();
});
```

For example, in ASP.net, you use RegisterStartupScriptBlock to execute such code after ajax postback is completed:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "selectHandler", " $(body).on('change','#select',function(){//AJAX is called changeLength();});", true);
```

If you are using jQuery to do the ajax request and reconstruct the html select input in the page, you'll need to execute the same code block again and so on.